# Why are exotic options most popular in FX?

Tags: option-pricing, fx, modeling, exotics

I was reading Derman's latest [blog post](http://blogs.reuters.com/emanuelderman/2011/07/28/sophisticated-vulgarity-1/) on [Vanna Volga pricing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanna_Volga_pricing), which, according to the linked Wikipedia article, is used mostly for pricing [exotic options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_option) on foreign exchange (FX).  This [Willmott thread](http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?FTVAR_FORUMVIEWTMP=Threaded&catid=38&threadid=60321&messid=367091&ftvar_msgdbtable=#367091) claims most demand for exotics is by asset-liability, pensions, and insurance firms.  But this does not explain why most of the trading in these products is in FX, as opposed to equities, bonds, etc.  **Why are these firms trading FX exotics**, and, relatedly, **why are they not trading exotics in other products?**  Is it just the liquidity of FX vs. other markets, or is there a good fundamental reason for exotics to exist in FX and not in other markets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, the currency derivatives are meant for customers to hedge *actual exposure*. A foreign distributor obviously has exchange-rate risk, but it's hard to say who actually has risk exposure to the S&P 500. (There's the effect of beta, of course, but it's pretty rare for someone to have tangible---not just CAPM---exposure to the S&P. Someone who holds the S&P does so intentionally.)

Fear not, though. There are a few OTC derivatives that are used in levered ETFs. Consider [3X Russell 2000](http://www.direxionshares.com/holdings_tna.csv) or [Ultra NASDAQ 100](http://www.proshares.com/funds/qld_daily_holdings.html?show=all), both of which list index swaps among their holdings.

Answer (score 5):

1. Liquidity
2. Since this is an asset class which is so tightly coupled with interest rates - it makes good products for clients inherently complex.
3. It also makes good sense to make wider markets for more exotic products than the plain vanilla ones - in which razor-thin spreads rule (and trading huge notionals is not everyone's cup of tea)

Answer (score 2):

Posting this question to a LinkedIn discussion group solicited the following additional answers:

1. The underlying is relatively well understood and simple in a pricing sense.  This allows you to put a complex (exotic) payoff on top.
2. The vast majority of FX spot volumes are spread among a small group of G-7 currencies, unlike equities or other markets where you have a myriad of different tickers.
3. No major barriers to the market / inside information / absence of manipulators (except for Central Banks who do not have speculative missions).
4. Pension and insurance firms are taking deposits in one currency which they invest in a different currency for carry/performance.  They only partially hedge their currency exposure using options, and sometimes exotic OTC options are designed in order to best fit their particular mix of assets and liabilities.

I do have my own question on point #2, though.  Aren't there relatively few highly liquid equity indices and fixed income futures?  Why don't we see more S&P 500 or US 10Y Treasury exotics?

**Update:** I actually like #4, which just came in from LinkedIn, best so far.  Basically, the real-world exposure of unsophisticated firms is complicated, and so they offload the complex hedging to a sophisticated counterparty.  This, combined with @chrisaycock's answer, completely answers the question to my satisfaction.